# How can I populate a query string variable to a text box which contains &,\ and $ in it

Tags: request.querystring, querystringparameter

I have a variable like say `A= drug & medicare $12/$15`.

I need to assign it to a text box, but only 'drug' is posted the server. The rest of the data gets truncated.

```
this.textbox.text= request.querystring["A"].tostring();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Typically questions here include some code. Can you include some code so we have an idea what platform you're using? Is it PHP? Ruby on Rails? Asp.NET?

Comment: If you add the tag for the language you will get more and better help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have problems with HTML entities. You need to read up on HTML escaping in your tool of choice. `&` cannot stand in HTML, since it begins an entity sequence - it needs to be replaced with `&amp;`. Without specifying at least which toolchain you're using (as per @Richard's comment), we can't really suggest the best way to do it.

**EDIT:** Now that I reread your question, it seems A is not a variable but a query parameter :) Reading comprehension fail. Anyway, in this case a similar problem exists: & is not a valid character for a query parameter, and it needs URL escaping. Again, how exactly to do it is in the documentation for your toolchain, but in essence & will need to be replaced by `%26`. Plus sign is also not permitted (or rather it has another meaning); others are tolerated (but there are nicer ways to write them).

Answer (score 0):

The following is not valid for a="foo&bar$12":

```
http://example.com?a=foo&bar$12
```

The & symbol is a reserved character, it seperates query string variables.  You will need to percent encode a value before sending them to that page.

Also & is a reserved character in HTML/XML.  I suggest reading up on percent encoding and html encoding.

Comment: hai nate thanks a bunch with out disturbing the url is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

That looks more or less like ASP.NET pseudocode, so I'm going to diagnose your problem as the query string needing to be URL encoded. Key/value pairs in the query string are separated by an ampersand (&), and ASP.NET (along with other web platforms) automatically parse out the key value pairs for you.

In this case, the ampersand terminates the value of the "A=..." key/value pair. The problem will be solved if you can URL encode the link that brings the user into your page. If actually using ASP.NET, you can use the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) for that:

```
string myValue = Server.UrlEncode("drug & medicare $12/$15");
```

You'll end up with this querystring instead: A=drug%20%26%20medicare%20%2412%2F%2415